# Setting value to the next available cell below

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this small piece of function that accepts these specific objects (itemNumber, qty, bStaff). When I run the code, the values were written in a specific location which is A13, C13, and F13 at the first time it runs. When I run the code again, how do I write the values directly to the cell below and so on up until a certain cell (limit)?

```
function submitBtn(itemNumber, qty, bStaff)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inventorySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var drSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

    drSheet.getRange("A13").setValue(qty);
    drSheet.getRange("C13").setValue(itemNumber);
    drSheet.getRange("F13").setValue(bStaff);
  
    
 
 
}
```

I tried doing for loops, but it only fills all the other cells with the same values. Maybe I was just doing it wrong. What I need is a function that adds an item, creating some kind of list of values every time it runs.

I also tried this but only sets Value for 1 cell and overwrites that cell when function runs again

```
    var lastRow = drSheet.getRange("A12").getLastRow(); 
    var values = drSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1);
    values.setValues(qty);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a row:

```
 const row = new Array(inventorySheet.getLastColumn()).fill('');
 row[1] = qty;
 row[3] = itemNumber;
 row[6] = bStaff;
```

Then you can either use:

```
 inventorySheet.appendRow(row);
```

or:

```
inventorySheet.getRange(inventorySheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 
  row.length).setValues([row]); // note the nested [row]
```

Comment: by using .getLastRow(), the function sets values below the limit range, how do I set them within a certain range? starting from row 13 and up until row 40. by "limit" I mean there are cells that should not be overwritten beyond it.

Comment: You can set up a condition: 

`let current = 13; const limit = 40; if (current < limit) { inventorySheet.getRange(current++, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);}`